# Why Ubuntu flavors don't share design themes?

Tags: themes, desktop-environments, colors, design

Why the different Ubuntu flavors don't have an unified (or at least aligned) theming and design language? Like for example Manjaro, that has several desktop environments (Gnome, Xfce, KDE) but all share icons, colours and other design cues.

Comment: There are complexities in some of what you mention, eg. GNOME & XFCE are based on GTK, where as KDE uses Qt.  Lubuntu was GTK2 (an old GTK version) up to 18.04, but started with a new desktop with 18.10 and so now uses Qt themes (on LXQt desktop).  How decisions are made can vary, but it's somewhat consensus by those building the flavor (the team), and whilst conversation between teams occurs many times a day, no team dares tell another team what to do (not even in jest; conversations are public)

Answer (score 1):

Each Ubuntu flavor is managed by a separate development team. This gives the opportunity for the flavors to deviate from what is available in Ubuntu.
It also helps with the branding of each flavor by being different.

Nevertheless, it requires effort to adapt the theming for one desktop environment to another.